# ClassCastException after checking of instanceOf

Tags: grails, groovy, classcastexception

I Have grails (version 3.2.11) application (it includes groovy-2.4.11.jar).
And following code

```
 @CompileStatic
def removeAllErrors(DomainClass domainInstance) {
    newAssociationOperationRunnerBuilder(domainInstance)
    .setSkipChain({DomainObjectDetails<DomainObjectDataSingle> domainObjectDetails ->
        skipValidation(domainObjectDetails.currentDomain.domainObject, domainObjectDetails.associationProp?.name)})
    .build().run({DomainObjectDetails<DomainObjectDataSingle> domainObjectDetails ->
        DomainClass domain = domainObjectDetails.currentDomain.domainObject
        if (domain instanceof GormValidateable) {
            ((GormValidateable)domain).clearErrors()
        }
        if(domain instanceof WarningsHolder) {
            WarningsHolder warningsHolder = domain as WarningsHolder //<--- line 120
            Warnings warnings = warningsHolder.getWarnings()
            warnings.clearWarnings(false, true)
        }
    })
}
```

And I am getting following exception

```
2018-06-14 10:16:41,647 ERROR StackTrace - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@3f6e3869
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5958.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1125)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:925)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:908)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:591)
    at com.webbfontaine.grails.plugins.validation.rules.DocVerificationService$_removeAllErrors_closure5.doCall(DocVerificationService.groovy:120)
```

Any idea what can be the reason ?
Pay attention that I have @CompileStatic there also.

=========================================================================
Previous version of this code  was without @CompileStatic

```
 def removeAllErrors(def domainInstance) {
    newAssociationOperationRunnerBuilder(domainInstance)
    .setSkipChain({DomainObjectDetails<DomainObjectDataSingle> domainObjectDetails ->
        skipValidation(domainObjectDetails.currentDomain.domainObject, domainObjectDetails.associationProp?.name)})
    .build().run({DomainObjectDetails<DomainObjectDataSingle> domainObjectDetails ->
        domainObjectDetails.currentDomain.domainObject.clearErrors()
        if(domainObjectDetails.currentDomain.domainObject instanceof WarningsHolder) {
            Warnings warnings = domainObjectDetails.currentDomain.domainObject.getWarnings()
            warnings.clearWarnings(false, true)
        }
    })
}
```

And I was getting this exception

```
com.webbfontaine.sw.sad.ci.Item cannot be cast to com.webbfontaine.sw.sad.ci.Item_$$_jvst840_3. Stacktrace follows: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.webbfontaine.sw.sad.ci.Item cannot be cast to com.webbfontaine.sw.sad.ci.Item_$$_jvst840_3
at com.webbfontaine.grails.plugins.validation.rules.DocVerificationService$_removeAllErrors_closure5.doCall(DocVerificationService.groovy:111)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `instanceof` with proxies at all, as it' going to lead to unpredictable results.

If you want to check the objects for class, you can use either `isAssignableFrom()`:

```
if ( GormValidateable.isAssignableFrom( domain.getClass() ) ) {...}
```

or `isCase()` / `switch`:

```
switch( domain ){
  case GormValidateable: doStuff(); break
  case WarningsHolder: doOtherSTuff(); break
}
```